# Printing an array object using a simple print method

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, methods

How can I refer to the object on which I'm implementing the instance method. I wrote a class called `MatrixMaker` that looks like this:

```
package one;

public class MatrixMaker {

private int rows;
private int columns;

public MatrixMaker(int m, int n){
    rows = m;
    columns = n;
    double[][] matrix = new double[rows][columns];

}

public void printer(){
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){

        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){

            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

}

I initialized an object in this class using:

```
MatrixMaker matrix = new MatrixMaker(3,4);
```

My question is how do I use

```
matrix.printer();
```

to print the array. I can't seem to refer to the contents of the object inside the method `printer()`. Specifically the line:

```
System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
```

Comment: Define `double[][] matrix` in your class scope. So place it where `private int columns;` is.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `double[][] matrix` variable is local to the constructor, so it only exists within the scope of the constructor. Make it an instance variable in order to access it from other methods.

```
public class MatrixMaker {

private int rows;
private int columns;
private double[][] matrix;

public MatrixMaker(int m, int n){
    rows = m;
    columns = n;
    matrix = new double[rows][columns];

}
```

This would make it accessible to the `printer` method.
    ...

Comment: It worked! Thanks again. I should've thought of that.

Answer (score 2):

Your `matrix` array is a *local variable* inside the constructor `MatrixMaker(int m, int n)`. If you make it into a member variable you will be able to access it from other methods.

```
public class MatrixMaker {

    private int rows;
    private int columns;
    private double[][] matrix;

    public MatrixMaker(int m, int n){
        rows = m;
        columns = n;
        matrix = new double[rows][columns];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined matrix as a local variable to the constructor of Matrix class. This class won't compile.

Try defining your matrix as a field:

```
public class MatrixMaker {

    private int rows;
    private int columns;
    private double[][] matrix;

    public MatrixMaker(int m, int n){
        rows = m;
        columns = n;
        matrix = new double[rows][columns];

    }

    public void printer(){
        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare the variable matrix inside your class to make it a member variable, not as local variable in the constructor.

```
public class MatrixMaker(int m, int n) {
    private int rows;
    private int columns;
    private double[][] matrix;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatrixMaker {

private int rows;
private int columns;
double[][] matrix;

public MatrixMaker(int m, int n){
rows = m;
columns = n;
matrix = new double[rows][columns];

}

public void printer(){
  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){

    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){

        System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+"  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  MatrixMaker m=new MatrixMaker(4,4);
  Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter Matrix Elements:");
  for(int i=0;i<m.rows;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<m.columns;j++)
        m.matrix[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(in.next());
      }

   in.close();

  m.printer();
}

}
```

Provide Input in The Console as Follows:

```
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
```

Or you may Provide Input numbers one by one,as:
1
2
3
4
5
6
..